# Application showing an exception"file not found "

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0

1. I created an application in VS2010 with operating system WINDOWS XP.
2. Now, I updated the os to WIN 7 and also updated the location of the application.
3. So, while running the application for opening a file using open dialog box  it showing some exception like"File Not Found".
4. It was working fine with WIN XP, but now it showing this error, if we keep that perticular file in bin folder its working fine , but if we choose a file from other drive or a folder it showing error.

   enter code here

   ```
   string chosen_file = "";
   ofd.Title = "Open a file";
   ofd.FileName = "";
   ofd.Filter = "Text Files(*.txt)|*.txt|Rich Text Box(*.rtb)|*.rtb|Word Document(*.doc)|*.doc|HTML Pages(*.htm)|*.html|Cascading Style Sheet(*.css)|*.css|JAVA(*.java)|*.java|video file(*.wmv)|*.wmv|All Files(*.*)|*.*";
   if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
   {
       chosen_file = ofd.FileName;
       // richTextBox2.LoadFile(chosen_file, RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);

       var fileInfo = new FileInfo(ofd.FileName);
       fileInfo.Length.ToString();
       byte[] buffer = new byte[fileInfo.Length];

       int length = (int)fileInfo.Length;
       FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(fileInfo.Name, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
       fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, length);}
   ```

Comment: Do **not** use FileInfo.Name when opening the FileStream.  That's only the name of the file, not the full path of the file.  So is guaranteed to fail when you pick a file from another directory.  You must use ofd.FileName instead.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you referenced a hard-coded path, probably to your "Documents" folder, rather than using an environment variable.  With the change from XP to 7, that directory changed.  I can't recall what the directory was for Windows XP, but it's now /users/username for Windows 7.  Either way, you would be better off using an environment variable.

Look through your program for `Documents and Settings` and see if you can find it.  If you go to a command prompt and type `set,` it should give you a list of environment variables you could use in place of whatever you were using.

Comment: In above problem I added some code will it help you to understand,sorry because I didn't get you

Comment: I didn't set that, but it going to C: only

Comment: It showing this exception"Could not find file 'D:\Rakesh Backup\Backup1\Binary Soft22july\NoteBook\bin\Debug\New Text Document (2).txt'."

Comment: yes,At this line I am getting exception" FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(fileInfo.Name, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);" and the exception is""Could not find file 'D:\Rakesh Backup\Backup1\Binary Soft22july\NoteBook\bin\Debug\New Text Document (2).txt'."

Comment: only the files within the bin folder are able to open other than that it showing the exception

Comment: But requirement is client can open any file and from any drive

Comment: No sir, it  will not help me.My problem is different.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm at the point where I really need your solution in action to pinpoint the issue...  I wish I could help more

Comment: So how would I help you sir to get the solution

Comment: Dont worry, and thank you very much sir for replying to my questions @Hambone